# How to upload image from React-Native to Laravel backend?

Tags: laravel, react-native, file-upload

I made a Laravel backend to receive image from React-Native app.
I tested on postman and it is working well.
But I am not sure how do I write RN code with the postman code.

[image]

How to upload image in React Native?
I used "react-native-image-crop-picker".

Answer (score 2):

I found answer.

```
try{
    let uploadData = new FormData();
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    myHeaders.append("gb-auth-token", myToken);

    uploadData.append('profile_img', {
        type: 'image/jpeg', 
        uri: profileImage,     // e.g: file:///storage/......./blabla.jpg
        name: 'upload.jpg'
    })
    uploadData.append("customer_id", id);
    const response = await fetch(CUSTOMER_PP, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: uploadData
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

> In this code, this is core.

```
    uploadData.append('profile_img', {
        type: 'image/jpeg', 
        uri: profileImage,     // This value comes from "react-native-image-crop-picker" response.path
        name: 'upload.jpg'
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful.